# Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI

Tags: solr

I kept getting the error ***"Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI"*** while trying to setup SOLR on windows x64 machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resolution to the problem is really simple.
1)start solr. notice that you have to use solr.cmd instead of just solr

`*bin/solr.cmd start*`

2) then create the collection:

`*bin/solr.cmd create -c gettingstarted -p 8983*`

3) then add file/s to index using post tool. You can execute the post command in two ways

a)`java -Dc=gettingstarted -jar post.jar *.json`

or

b) `bin/post -c gettingstarted example/exampledocs/books.json`

Now you can navigate to your newly created collection 'gettingstarted' and query your books.

`http://localhost:8983/solr/#/gettingstarted/query'

Hope this saves someone's time.

Answer (score 0):

import datas in a core using one of those commands:

**Windows**:

```
bin\solr post -url http://localhost:8983/solr/tech_products/update example\exampledocs\*.xml
```

**macOs/Linux**

```
bin/solr post -url http://localhost:8983/solr/tech_products/update example/exampledocs/*.xml
```