# Solr Error : could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.solrcli

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, solr

I have a ROR project and from frew days, when i run service solr status, i get :

> Solr process 17919 running on port 8983 Error : could not find or load
>   main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCli

i'm new about solr, someone could help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.util.SolrCLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059709/could-not-find-or-load-main-class-org-apache-solr-util-solrcli)

Comment: No, i dont'have to setup solr... i used it until few days ago.

Comment: The problem is caused by being unable to load the class file - are you running it from the expected directory?

Comment: How can i check it? sorry but i'm new on solr.